# Jest-puppeteer preset config

Tags: javascript, configuration, automated-tests, jest-puppeteer

I create a new project, i have npm: '9.8.1',node: '18.18.0. I followed the quickstart.
I tried running the example:

```
describe('Google', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await page.goto('https://google.com');
  });

  it('should be titled "Google"', async () => {
    await expect(page.title()).resolves.toMatch('Google');
  });
});
```

the test passed but puppeteer opens a lot of browsers.

while in my test:

Tests.js

```
const Puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require('fs');
 


beforeAll(async () => {

  const path = process.env.VAR_ENV;



  const jsonFilePath = path;

  const jsonData = fs.readFileSync(jsonFilePath, 'utf-8');

  const dati = JSON.parse(jsonData);

  await page.goto(dati.URL)



  const coockie_button = 'button[class="amecp_button-accetto iubenda-cs-accept-btn"]';

  const searchSelector = 'input[id="gz-header-search-input"]';



  await page.waitForSelector(coockie_button);

  await page.click(coockie_button, { clickCount: 1 });

  await page.waitForSelector(searchSelector);

  await page.click(searchSelector, { clickCount: 1 });

  await page.type(searchSelector, dati.Recipe);

  await page.keyboard.press("Enter");

});




 it("Given 'Hello World!', return 'Hello World!'", async () => {

     expect('hello').toBe('hello');

  });
```

The test failed and gives me this error: ReferenceError: page is not defined.
So I don't know what the problem is.

I tried a lot of things also to reinstall all modules but nothing.
This is my json file for configuration:

package.json

```
"name": "jest-puppeteer-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "test_p": "cross-env VAR_ENV=C:/src/Prova/config/Test_config.json jest Test",
    "produzione": "cross-env VAR_ENV=C:/src/Prova/config/Produzione_config.json jest Test"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-puppeteer": "^9.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^21.3.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "es6": "^0.0.7",
    "expect-puppeteer": "^9.0.0",
    "jest-environment-puppeteer": "^9.0.0"
  }
}
```

jest-puppeteer.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    launch: {
        headless: false
    },
    browserContext: 'default'
}
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "jest-puppeteer",
  verbose: true
};
```